# How to make text inherit two values based on its condition?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a modal box called sectors.

Within my modal box I have created a line of code where the text will change color on click, but I want the original text color to be blue.

I have tried setting the original font color to blue; but then the text does not change color on click.

```html
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- jQuery Modal -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

</head>


    <style>
.onlyThese{
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-moz-user-select: none;     
-ms-user-select: none;      
 user-select: none;           
}




input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 
}




input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 

input:focus{
    outline: none;   
}

    </style>

<body>


<p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> </p>
     
<div id="ex5"; class="modal"; style="background-color:white">
     
<div style="float:left;">

<p> <input type="checkbox" id="group1"> <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label> </p>


</div>





                
    
<div>
<p style="float:right"> 
<a href="#" rel="modal:close"; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a> 
</p>    
</div>

</div>
  


    <script>
    
  $('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).modal({
        escapeClose: false,
        clickClose: false,
        showClose: false,
      });
    });
    
    </script>
```

The text will change color from blue to red and when its red the checkbox will be checked. When it is blue the checkbox will be un-checked. The checkbox is invisible but the color of the text signals whether it is checked or not.

Comment: I don't get it. It starts out blue and the gets red when you click it. What's the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick.

Notice this line:
`input[type="checkbox"]+label {  color:blue } // Default state`

```html
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- jQuery Modal -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

</head>


    <style>
.onlyThese{
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-moz-user-select: none;     
-ms-user-select: none;      
 user-select: none;           
}


input[type="checkbox"]+label {  color:blue } // Default state

input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 
}




input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 

input:focus{
    outline: none;   
}

    </style>

<body>


<p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> </p>
     
<div id="ex5"; class="modal"; style="background-color:white">
     
<div style="float:left;">

<p> <input type="checkbox" id="group1"> <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label> </p>


</div>





                
    
<div>
<p style="float:right"> 
<a href="#" rel="modal:close"; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a> 
</p>    
</div>

</div>
  


    <script>
    
  $('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).modal({
        escapeClose: false,
        clickClose: false,
        showClose: false,
      });
    });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Great exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in your styles:

```
input[type="checkbox"]+label{ color:blue; }
```